# Magento 2 certain products hide out of stock products at storefront

Tags: configuration, products, magento2.4, out-of-stock

I wanted to show all out of products at front store, so I went `Store> Configuration > Catalog > Inventory` and set yes `Display Out of Stock Products` option

But I have to hide certain out of stock products manually. So Default Magento 2 provides functionality where hide some products at item level configuration ? If yes, how ? If any extension please let me know. I am tired but I could not find the solution for this.

I am using community magento 2.4.0

Comment: Can you disable them?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I do not want to disable them

Comment: Magento default doesn't have this feature, you need to write code for it

Answer (score 1):

I know its very late to respond now, but anyone else looking for solution, one can set visibility to not visible individually or search only if want them to keep visible in search. that will hide product from front end.

Comment: it won't work with configurable's child item

Comment: if you are not displaying configurable child products separately, then you can disable them, so technically you can use mixed solution, for simple products set visibility and for configurable child product set status to disabled (if not shown separately)

Answer (score 0):

I have created one custom attribute `show_item` and filter custom attribute by override `vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter.php`

Answer (score -2):

You can use this extension to solve your problem: https://marketplace.magento.com/mediarox-module-out-of-stock-last.html

Comment: I asked for hide certain out of stock products,but your extension shows out of stock products in last.It means it will be show all the out of stock products.Please correct your answer.I will be wait your answer

Comment: This is not an answer and it is just adv for selling a not that much usable module!!